# Read a table from a file with nullable columns

Tags: c#, file

I have a file with some rows and I can read everything, but I will get an error if one column has a empty cell.

What should I do?

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    FundPriceModel model = new FundPriceModel();

    if (isColumn) {
        model.Columns = line.Split(spliter[0]);
        isColumn = false;
    } else {
        string[] row = line.Split(spliter);

        model.LipperID = Int32.Parse(row[0]);
        model.PriceDate = DateTime.Parse(row[1]);
        model.PriceCode = row[2][0];
        model.PriceType = row[3][0];
        model.PriceCurrency = row[4];
        model.PriceValueLC = float.Parse(row[5]);
        model.Estimate = row[6][0];

        Console.WriteLine(model.LipperID + "\t" + model.PriceDate + "\t" + model.PriceCode + "\t" + model.PriceType + "\t" + model.PriceCurrency + "\t" + model.PriceValueLC + "\t" + model.Estimate);
    }
}
```

Table:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably when you try to parse something. This leads me to believe that you need to use TryParse instead or Parse :)
Something like this: `int x; int? val=int.TryParse(row[0],out x)?x:(int?)null;`

Also, row[3][0] gets the first letter in an existing string and returning an error when the string is empty. You could encapsulate it somewhat like this:

```
private T safeValue<T>(string text, Func<string,T> func) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return default(T);
  return func(text)
}
```

and you would use it like this:

```
model.LipperID = safeValue(row[0],v=>Int32.Parse(v));
model.PriceCode = safeValue(row[2], v=>v[0]);
```

Comment: no its not because of parsing. see the table file below. in the last column there are some E for some reason, but not for every row. so if i file all rows with those E i wont get any problems. its because its possible to read from nothing and thats the problem. and i dont know how to handle it now.